# Why do I get conflicting types for "FONT" and other structs in my bootloader?

Tags: c, struct

I am currently working on a bootloader with some friends but I cannot figure this out. These are the structs.

```c
typedef struct {
    void* BaseAddress; // a void pointer holds the address of any type of variable
    size_t BufferSize; // controls how big the buffer is (a buffer is a little place of data)
    unsigned int Width, Height;
    // screen height and width
    unsigned int PixelsPerScanLine; // Pixels per scan line is how you determinine your refresh rate
} Framebuffer; // the name of the class and what this class does is outputs the pixels

typedef struct {
    unsigned char magic[2]; // we call it magic because this is the bytes the header stores that lets us identify that the psf file is a psf file
    unsigned char mode; // the mode that the psf font is in
    unsigned char charsize; // defines how large the characters are in bytes
} FONT_HEADER;

typedef struct {
    FONT_HEADER* fontHdr;
    void* glyphBuffer; // keeps data about the piece of text or character
} FONT;
```

These are the structs that have errors, the errors below state that there was a previous declaration of the struct or type but it is in the same place as where the error is.

```
In file included from src_uefi/main_uefi.c:9:
src_uefi/include/fb.h:15:3: error: conflicting types for ‘Framebuffer’
   15 | } Framebuffer; // the name of the class and what this class does is outputs the pixels
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from src_uefi/include/gop.h:2,
                 from src_uefi/main_uefi.c:4:
src_uefi/include/fb.h:15:3: note: previous declaration of ‘Framebuffer’ was here
   15 | } Framebuffer; // the name of the class and what this class does is outputs the pixels
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from src_uefi/main_uefi.c:9:
src_uefi/include/fb.h:17:20: error: conflicting types for ‘fb’
   17 | extern Framebuffer fb;
      |                    ^~
In file included from src_uefi/include/gop.h:2,
                 from src_uefi/main_uefi.c:4:
src_uefi/include/fb.h:17:20: note: previous declaration of ‘fb’ was here
   17 | extern Framebuffer fb;
      |                    ^~
In file included from src_uefi/main_uefi.c:9:
src_uefi/include/fb.h:26:3: error: conflicting types for ‘FONT_HEADER’
   26 | } FONT_HEADER;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from src_uefi/include/gop.h:2,
                 from src_uefi/main_uefi.c:4:
src_uefi/include/fb.h:26:3: note: previous declaration of ‘FONT_HEADER’ was here
   26 | } FONT_HEADER;
      |   ^~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from src_uefi/main_uefi.c:9:
src_uefi/include/fb.h:31:3: error: conflicting types for ‘FONT’
   31 | } FONT;
      |   ^~~~
In file included from src_uefi/include/gop.h:2,
                 from src_uefi/main_uefi.c:4:
src_uefi/include/fb.h:31:3: note: previous declaration of ‘FONT’ was here
   31 | } FONT;
      |   ^~~~
In file included from src_uefi/main_uefi.c:9:
src_uefi/include/fb.h:34:7: error: conflicting types for ‘LoadFont’
   34 | FONT* LoadFont(EFI_FILE_PROTOCOL* Directory, CHAR16* Path, EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* SystemTable);
      |       ^~~~~~~~
In file included from src_uefi/include/gop.h:2,
                 from src_uefi/main_uefi.c:4:
src_uefi/include/fb.h:34:7: note: previous declaration of ‘LoadFont’ was here
   34 | FONT* LoadFont(EFI_FILE_PROTOCOL* Directory, CHAR16* Path, EFI_HANDLE ImageHandle, EFI_SYSTEM_TABLE* SystemTable);
      |       ^~~~~~~~
src_uefi/main_uefi.c: In function ‘main_uefi’:
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:141:83: error: initialization of ‘int (__attribute__((sysv_abi)) *)(Framebuffer *, FONT,  BootInfo *)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘int (__attribute__((sysv_abi)) *)(BootInfo *)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  141 |     __attribute__((sysv_abi)) int (*KernelEntry)(Framebuffer*, FONT, BootInfo*) = ((__attribute__((sysv_abi)) int (*)(BootInfo*) ) kernel_elf_header->e_entry);
      |                                                                                   ^
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:159:33: error: initialization of ‘Framebuffer *’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous> *’} from incompatible pointer type ‘Framebuffer *’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous> *’} [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  159 |     Framebuffer* kernelBuffer = initGOP();
      |                                 ^~~~~~~
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:161:17: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
  161 |     kernelBuffer->BaseAddress;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:162:17: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
  162 |     kernelBuffer->BufferSize;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:163:17: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
  163 |     kernelBuffer->Width;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:164:17: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
  164 |     kernelBuffer->Height;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:165:17: error: statement with no effect [-Werror=unused-value]
  165 |     kernelBuffer->PixelsPerScanLine;
      |     ~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:167:31: error: incompatible type for argument 2 of ‘KernelEntry’
  167 |     KernelEntry(kernelBuffer, kernelFont, bootinfo);
      |                               ^~~~~~~~~~
      |                               |
      |                               FONT * {aka struct <anonymous> *}
src_uefi/main_uefi.c:167:31: note: expected ‘FONT’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous>’} but argument is of type ‘FONT *’ {aka ‘struct <anonymous> *’}
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
```

What am I doing wrong and what do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

In researching this issue, I found this similar issue out on the web that seems to relate to the same problem [Conflicting type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288566/previous-declaration-of-was-here-and-conflicting-types-for-put-non-bloccante).

I tested out some scenarios and it most likely looks like within your "gop.h" header file, there is a statement to include the "fb.h" header file.

```
#include fb.h
```

Then within your "main.c" program you most likely have include statements for both "fb.h" and "gop.h" files as in the following code snippet.

```
#include "fb.h"
#include "gop.h"
```

So, the structure definitions are getting referenced a second time.

That is the most likely cause.  If that is indeed the case, you probably will want to look at the proposed solution within the link I referenced.

Hope that helps.

Regards.

Comment: Thank you, this helps alot. I have other errors awell that were not resolved. https://pastebin.com/EBRNe0Bc

Answer (score 0):

Add [code guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard#Use_of_#include_guards) to `fb.h` to allow it to be included multiple times.

Comment: Thankyou, I did not realize that I did not put a #pragma once in the fb.h which resolved a lot of the errors

Comment: `#pragma once` is a non-standard solution.